# How to replace or insert a character on multiple locations on a string using substr_replace, can I add more than one position on the function?

Tags: php, substr

As the title says

I want to insert or replace, a comma ( ,) into a string.

I have this string : A fits B fits C fits D. I want to insert comma behind every fits and right after the word before fits.

This is the desired result : `A, fits B, Fits C, Fits D`

The code I am using to achieve that is :

```
$newstr = substr_replace($oldstr,", ",stripos($oldstr,"fits")-1,0);
```

However, this code only insert 1 comma in the first occurrence of "fits".
I tried using `substr_count()` to get the count of fits occurring and then uses `For loop` but the comma is stacked in the position of the first occurrence of fits.

like this : `A,,, Fits B Fits C Fits D`

There must be a way to achieve the desired result, it has to be with adding more than one position in `substr_replace()` function or something right?

**EDIT**

The string I have is `White Fits Black Fits Red Fits Blue`
The desired result is `White, Fits Black, Fits Red, Fits Blue`

The comma `,` is placed behind every `Fits` word in the string AND right after the word behind `fits`

the key point of my question is : How to put comma in behind every `fits` word AND right after the word behind `fits`

Thanks before

Comment: Please don't change your question after others have already answered.

Comment: Sorry about that I was oversimplifying my question before

Comment: No issues, just giving you some feedback should you use the site again in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace`:

```
$input = "A fits B Fits C Fits D";
$output = preg_replace("/\b([A-Z]+)(?=\s)/", "$1,", $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
A fits B Fits C Fits D
A, fits B, Fits C, Fits D
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

\b([A-Z]+)    match AND capture one or more uppercase letters, which are preceded
by a word boundary
(?=\s)       then assert that what follows is a space; this prevents a final
letter from being assigned a comma, should the input end in a letter

Then, we replace with `$1`, the captured letter(s), followed by a comma.

**Edit:**

For your recent edit, you may use:

```
$input = "White Fits Black Fits Red Fits Blue";
$output = preg_replace("/\b(?=\s+Fits\b)/", ",", $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
White Fits Black Fits Red Fits Blue
White, Fits Black, Fits Red, Fits Blue
```

Comment: Thank you, I will read about preg_replace first then come back here to understand more

Comment: This function put comma exactly right after the uppercase letter. But what if it is not uppercase letter but instead a word? The key is each Comma will be put behind every Fits word and right after the word before fits

Comment: That substantially changes the question you asked, and invalidates my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I should learn more about regex. I just don't understand the pattern but I know how the function works